# Separate text by delimiter SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, charindex

I need some help to separate the text by the delimiter `/`, and get the 3rd argument, I know that with the functions `CHARINDEX`, `SUBSTRING`, `CASE, THEN, WHEN`... it's possible, but I'm having difficulty.

Database details:

```
AE/SREW/SWERR/REEEM/RRTS
AI/SREW/RUYE/REMC/DOR
AR/SRTE/RIRRH/PROTRED
AE/ASDEE/RIRRH/PROTRED/SEDRR
AE/FGY/RH/VETSDEE/AIURD
TA/PA/RHNEW/SERJJ/CENTER/FERT
FJHDE
FJHDE/YREY
```

I ran the following query, but got the following result:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(values, CHARINDEX('/', values, (CHARINDEX('/', values) + 1)) + 1, LEN(values)) AS Result
FROM
    dbtable
```

Result:

```
SWERR/REEEM/RRTS
RUYE/REMC/DOR
RIRRH/PROTRED
RIRRH/PROTRED/SEDRR
HR/VETSDEE/AIURD
RHNEW/SERJJ/CENTER/FERT
FJHDE
FJHDE/YREY
```

Desired result:

```
ANSWER
RUYE
RIRRH
RIRRH
HR
RHNEW
FJHDE -> For cases where there is no "/", put the text 'OTHER'.
FJHDE/YREY -> For cases where there is "/" only one (1), "/", put the text 'OTHER'.
```

Best regards.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to correct the "Desired result" values.

Comment: Is there any chance of restructuring the database so that the individual items are rows in a separate table instead of being in one column? That would make the query much simpler.

Comment: You could make your sample data a lot easier on the eye with just using *words*. Your first line has `/SWERR/` and you expect `ANSWER`. Just using A, B, C... would make things much simpler.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 2):

You can transform those strings into the format of a JSON array.
Then pick the 2th key from that. *(the key starts at 0)*

> ```
> SELECT ISNULL(a.value, 'OTHER') AS Result
> FROM dbtable t
> OUTER APPLY (
>   SELECT j.value
>   FROM OPENJSON('["'+REPLACE(t.[values],'/', '","')+'"]') j
>   WHERE j.[key] = 2
> ) a;
> ```

> | Result |
> | --- |
> | SWERR |
> | RUYE |
> | RIRRH |
> | RIRRH |
> | RH |
> | RHNEW |
> | OTHER |
> | OTHER |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=63dfb3fbdd2a6d815f8d04386c27e04d)*

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the wrong length to the [`SUBSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function, which is why you're getting the result from 2nd / up until the end. I broke it down with `CROSS APPLY` for 2nd and 3rd /:

```
SELECT vals,
    split2.idx, split3.idx,
    CASE 
      WHEN split2.idx = 0 THEN 'OTHER'
      ELSE SUBSTRING(vals, split2.idx+1, split3.idx - split2.idx - 1)
    END as third
FROM
    tb
CROSS 
APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('/', vals, CHARINDEX('/', vals)+1) as idx) split2
CROSS
APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('/', vals, split2.idx+1) as idx) split3
```

Alternatively, if you're on Azure SQL Database or using SQL Server 2022, you can simply use [STRING_SPLIT as described in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), with value and ordinal returned from the function.

If you're on SQL Server 2016 or 2019, with STRING_SPLIT but without the ordinal, you need sort of a hack using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0))` as the function doesn't really tell you which string is at which index:

```
SELECT tb.vals, ISNULL(MAX(IIF(ordinal = 3, value, NULL)), 'OTHER')
  FROM tb
 CROSS
 APPLY (SELECT value
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as ordinal 
          FROM STRING_SPLIT(tb.vals, '/')
     ) split
 GROUP BY tb.vals
```

The way this works is uses the `STRING_SPLIT` function to split each of the values into rows containing the individual substrings. `ROW_NUMBER()` ordered by a literal is used to then give the index, although no actual guarantee is ever made by Microsoft that the substrings will be returned from the function in order of occurrence, that's why it's a hack. Then, all of these rows are aggregated and, in the `MAX` aggregation function we select the 3rd occurrence. If no such occurence is found, the `IIF` statement will return all NULLs and `MAX` in turn will also be NULL, which we then substitute for 'OTHER', as per requirements.

[Working demo on dbfiddle for both solutions](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c4c90a5ab18ec07248f26ede3052c082)